# Deploy converted oozie DAG into Google Composer Airflow: No module named 'o2a'

Tags: python, airflow, oozie, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I'm using [google oozie to airflow converter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/oozie-to-airflow) to convert some oozie workflow that are running on AWS EMR. Managed to get a first version, but when I try to upload the DAG, airflow throws an error:

***Broken DAG: No module named 'o2a'***

I have tried to deploy the pypi package o2a, both using command

```
gcloud composer environments update composer-name --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt --location location
```

And from google cloud console. Both failed.

requirements.txt

```
o2a==1.0.1
```

Here is the code

```
    from airflow import models
    from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator
    from airflow.utils import dates
    from o2a.o2a_libs import functions
    from airflow.models import Variable

    import subdag_validation
    import subdag_generate_reports

    CONFIG = {}

    JOB_PROPS = {

    }

    dag_config = Variable.get("coordinator", deserialize_json=True)
    cdrPeriod = dag_config["cdrPeriod"]

    TASK_MAP = {"validation": ["validation"], "generate_reports": ["generate_reports"] }

    TEMPLATE_ENV = {**CONFIG, **JOB_PROPS, "functions": functions, "task_map": TASK_MAP}

    with models.DAG(
        "workflow_coordinator",
        schedule_interval=None,  # Change to suit your needs
        start_date=dates.days_ago(0),  # Change to suit your needs
        user_defined_macros=TEMPLATE_ENV,
    ) as dag:

        validation = SubDagOperator(
            task_id="validation",
            trigger_rule="one_success",
            subdag=subdag_validation.sub_dag(dag.dag_id, "validation", dag.start_date, dag.schedule_interval),
        )

        generate_reports = SubDagOperator(
            task_id="generate_reports",
            trigger_rule="one_success",
            subdag=subdag_generate_reports.sub_dag(dag.dag_id, "generate_reports", dag.start_date, dag.schedule_interval,
            {
                "cdrPeriod": "{{cdrPeriod}}"
            }),
        )

        validation.set_downstream(generate_reports)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a section in the o2a docs that cover how to deploy o2a:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/oozie-to-airflow#the-o2a-libraries

With started to failed because another dependency:lark-parser
Just installed using pypi package manager for Composer did the trick.